# How to use a Gradle library catalog version directly in a dependency spec?

Tags: gradle

I'm using the new-ish `versionCatalogs` mechanism, as per [the doco](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:central-declaration-of-dependencies) (Gradle 7.5).

This is my library spec for Spring:

```groovy
dependencyResolutionManagement{
  versionCatalogs{
    libs{
      version('spring6', '6.0.0-M5')

      // core spring/web - pkg: org.springframework
      library('spring-webmvc', 'org.springframework', 'spring-webmvc').versionRef('spring6')
      // core spring/web security - pkg: import org.sf.security
      library('spring-security-core', 'org.springframework.security', 'spring-security-core').versionRef('spring6')
      // pkg: org.sf.security.web
      library('spring-security-web', 'org.springframework.security', 'spring-security-web').versionRef('spring6')
      // for configuring through code - pkg: org.sf.security.config
      library('spring-security-config', 'org.springframework.security', 'spring-security-config').versionRef('spring6')
      bundle('spring6', [
        'spring-webmvc',
        'spring-security-core',
        'spring-security-web',
        'spring-security-config',
      ])
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how I'm specifying the dependency on Spring:

```groovy
dependencies{
  implementation libs.bundles.spring6  

  // for integrating junit and spring - pkg: org.springframework.test
  testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-test:6.0.0-M5'
}
```

The problem is that I don't like the duplicated specification of the spring version (`6.0.0-M5` for `spring-test`).

Is there a syntax I can use to specify the `versionRef` directly on a library in a dependency block?

My current thought is that I'll need to create a `spring-test` catalog library in order to share the version number (moving the test lib into the library meant for prod is not an option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit verbose, but this seems to do the trick:

```groovy
  testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-test:' + libs.versions.spring6.get()
```